# Positioning ListViews in WinJS Metro apps using scrollIntoView

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

I am building a jscript-based Windows 8 Metro app. The main screen of this application is a scrolling "panorama" view with several list views showing various aspects of the app's state. In some cases the user will select something on the page which results in a navigation to another page (using the WinJS.Navigation.navigate method.

When the user hits the back arrow on the other page, it returns to the main screen, and I use "scrollIntoView" on to position the screen to the section that the user was working on before the navigation occurred.

Unfortunately this hardly ever results in correctly positioning the view. It seems random. I suspect that the page isn't finished being built yet and that the scroll values are set based on the state at some snapshot in time.

Now the question:

Is there some what to be notified by WinJS ListView objects that they are completely rendered and layed out? Or is this the job of the page's ready function?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting multiple list views side by side is Not A Good Idea(TM). I would recommend putting one list view, and placing your content in a grouped data source to get the groups. If the items have different templates, then you can use a custom item Template selector to dynamically select a template.

Additionally, to ensure that the list view is scrolled to the right position, you need to use the [indexOfFirstVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700691.aspx) to set the items the name suggests.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I suspected that the answer was something like that. :(